# Open Source tools to image a drive while OS is running?

Tags: windows, disk-image

In windows 7 are there any tools that are FOSS that can image a non-system drive while the OS is running?

I know there are tools such as Clonezilla, GParted, etc; but these are offline tools.

Comment: What sort of network/server environment is this running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool to do this; [it goes by ODIN](http://odin-win.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most journalling filesystems will support [snapshots](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2004/10/linux-20041013.ars). Although (IMHO) a more flexible approach is to break and remount a mirror (which allows you, e.g., start a new DBMS instance to run an application level extract of the data).

This provides you with an image against which you can run clonezilla, dd, cpio....